# How to get a list of all Wikidata properties?

Tags: wikidata, wikidata-api

What is the Wikidata API equivalent to [this page](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:List_of_properties/all_in_one_table) which lists all known Wikidata properties? I would like to search for a property, e.g. 'doctoral advisor', and get back P184.

A similar function exists for [items](http://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&sites=enwiki&titles=Berlin&languages=en), but I can't seem to find the equivalent for properties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Using `action=wbsearchentities` with `type=property`](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&search=doctoral%20advisor&language=en&type=property) should do. Wikidata API doc is [here](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php), search for "=wb" to get the Wikidata-specific functions.

Comment: Great, thanks, that looks great. So I can search, and I can get one property with [action=wbgetentities&ids=P17](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=P17), but what about the list of all properties?

Answer (score 6):

**Update**: thank to [@nerab's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35107309/3324977), I updated wikidata-properties-dumper to use [Quarry](http://quarry.wmflabs.org) SQL results: that's indead much cleaner :)

**Update 2**: Quarry wasn't that flexible, I moved to use a [SPARQL query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fproperty%20%3FpropertyLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fproperty%20a%20wikibase%3AProperty%20.%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%7D%0A%0ALIMIT%205) and wrapped that in a [Wikidata CLI](https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-cli) command: [`wd props`](https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-cli#wd-props)

I wrote a [small script to query all properties](https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-properties-dumper) with wikidata API's **action=wbgetentities**. It generate a json file with

> key: value

being

> property Pid: property label in the request language

I published the [outputs for a few languages](https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-properties-dumper/tree/master/properties) and could do for other language on request until there is an official (and cleaner) answer for this need

Comment: This CLI cannot be installed on Windows.

Comment: @sean it should be possible to install it on windows, if it fails that's a bug I would be happy to fix. Do you get that same error https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-cli/issues/72 or something else?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the comments in @maxlath's project, I found [Quarry](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Research:Quarry).

A list of all Wikidata properties can be fetched from

```
http://quarry.wmflabs.org/run/45013/output/1/json
```

This particular list is in English, but the [query](http://quarry.wmflabs.org/query/1248) can be modified for other languages, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this SPARQL query:
it returns property name, description and comma separated also known as labels from English language:

```
SELECT ?property ?propertyLabel ?propertyDescription (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(?altLabel); separator = ", ") AS ?altLabel_list) WHERE {
    ?property a wikibase:Property .
    OPTIONAL { ?property skos:altLabel ?altLabel . FILTER (lang(?altLabel) = "en") }
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .}
 }
GROUP BY ?property ?propertyLabel ?propertyDescription
LIMIT 5000
```